# How to correct this table text?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, formatting

I am working on a table, the code is:

```
\begin{table}[t!]
\small
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l|r@{ }r@{ }|r@{ }r@{ }|rrr@{ }}
    \toprule
    {} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bf Without  
Context} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bf Wiki} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bf Wiki 2}\\
    \midrule
    \bf Model & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Test} &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf Dev} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf Dev} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bf Dev}\\
    \midrule
    Albanian         &         565  &   755 &        1,194 &  311 &        1,194 &  311\\
    Arabic           &           1,194  &   562 &            1,194 &  1,194   &        1,194 &  311\\
    Bulgarian        &       1,100  & 1,472 &        2,344 &  593 &        1,194 &  311\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \caption{Number of examples in the data splits based on the experimental setup. 
    }
    \label{tab:datasplits}
\end{table}
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

But as it is visible that in dev set the values and Dev name is not aligned. How to make them aligh?

Comment: the tabular columns are right aligned but Dev is center aligned therefore the mis alignment

Comment: If I remove the `\centering`, still it's showing the same.

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf Dev}`  needs to be `\multicolumn{1}{r|}{\bf Dev}`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Please post it as an answer, I'll accept, Also how to reduce the gap between Test & Dev in the first column, let it be the same space as other two columns?

Comment: avoid applying `\resizebox` to tables it destroys any consistency in font sizes. Do not use vertical rules with the `booktabs` package (it breaks them by design) and note that `\bf` has not been defined by default in LaTeX since 1993, use `\bfseries`/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the tabular columns are right aligned but Dev is center aligned therefore the mis alignment

```
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bf Dev} needs to be \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\bf Dev}
```

to remove column space make use of `@{}` in the line of code between Test and Dev

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}r@{}r@{}r@{}r@{}|rrr@{}}
```

as rightly pointed out by David Carlisle in comments -- vertical lines should be avoided otherwise you will notice gaps since you are using toprule/midrule with the `booktabs`  package

Answer (score 3):

I would simplify and streamline the look of the table by getting rid of all vertical rules, all `\bf` statements, all `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` wrappers, and the `\resizebox` instruction. I'd also abbreviate "Without" as "w/o".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % select a suitable document class
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t!]
\small
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l rrrrrr @{}}
    \toprule
    {} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{w/o Context} 
       & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Wiki} 
       & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Wiki 2}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7}
    Model & Test & Dev & Test & Dev & Test & Dev \\
    \midrule
    Albanian         &   565  &   755 &  1,194 &   311 & 1,194 & 311\\
    Arabic           & 1,194  &   562 &  1,194 & 1,194 & 1,194 & 311\\
    Bulgarian        & 1,100  & 1,472 &  2,344 &   593 & 1,194 & 311\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Number of examples in the data splits based on the experimental setup.}
    \label{tab:datasplits}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```